# undefined columns selected：restart Rstudio and run the same code I used before I encounter this

Tags: r

here is my data,

```
> head(annotation)
  seqname    feature start   end
1       1 transcript 11869 14409
2       1       exon 11869 12227
3       1       exon 12613 12721
4       1       exon 13221 14409
5       1 transcript 11872 14412
6       1       exon 11872 12227
```

I want to extract the data with feature `transcript`, so I used

```
> annotation <- annotation[annotation$feature=='transcript']
Error in [.data.frame(annotation, annotation$feature == "transcript") : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I just used this command yesterday afternoon, and it functioned normally. 
I don't know why it gives me an error now.

```
> annotation$feature=='transcript'
   [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [13] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [49] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [61] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: It's unlikely that code worked before. It should be `annotation <- annotation[annotation$feature=='transcript', ]` (note the comma). Were you using a data.table before maybe instead of a data.frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that you are trying to select columns that do not exist. When subsetting a `data.frame`, if you do *not* use the multiple-index method (e.g., `mtcars[1,2]`) and instead just use a single number (`mtcars[1]`), it treats the data.frame like the `list` that it really is. As such, it gives you a single column of a data.frame.

For example, `mtcars` has 11 columns. If you index with a vector of `logical`s, it will return or not return each column based on the vector. Based on this, there should be no more than `ncol(mtcars)` values in that vector of logicals:

```
head(mtcars[rep(TRUE,11)])
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

mtcars[rep(TRUE,12)]
# Error in `[.data.frame`(mtcars, rep(TRUE, 12)) : 
#   undefined columns selected
```

Because you forgot a comma, your code `annotation$feature == "transcript"` is returning (at least) 72 `logical`s, which exceed the number of columns in your data.frame.

Try

```
annotation[annotation$feature=='transcript',]
```